# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: cli, wamp, magento2.4.0, mysql8

I'm trying to install Magento 2.4.0 and I keep getting the "Access Denied" for user:
`'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`
I'm using `Wamp64 Web Server` to configure it and using `Mysql 8.0.21`. I can see that my `root` user has all privileges' granted to the magento DB. Also, `root` has a password but is showing with NO Password. This is the install command I'm  trying:

```
Administrator@Windows MINGW64 /c/wamp64/www/magento
$ php bin/magento setup:install
--base-url=http://store.magento.com:8080/ 
--db-host=localhost
--db-name=magento
--db-user=root
--db-password=password123
--admin-firstname=magento
--admin-lastname=user
--admin-email=myuser@gmail.com
--admin-user=admin
--admin-password=password123
--language=en_US
--currency=USD
--timezone=America/Chicago
--use-rewrites=1
```

And, this is the response I get:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

In InstallCommand.php line 274:

Parameter validation failed
```

Could this be affected because my bash creds are showing as: `Administrator@Windows` or what should I be a checking to see that root has access?
Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to install `Magento 2.4.0` on Windows Server using `WAMP`. My user was setup correctly as administrator. It was an insignificant mistake, when using the terminal and writing the query to install, I had two spaces between the command arguments. So just make sure all your cmd arguments have just one space in between like this:

```
$ php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://store.magento.com:8080/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=root --db-password=password123 --admin-firstname=magento --admin-lastname=user --admin-email=myuser@gmail.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=password123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

And this, finally worked. I hope it helps if you run into this problem with a windows machine... and for that fact with Linux systems too. The whole thing is to **properly form your command arguments**. Thanks!